# Save postgresql query in computer

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have this problem that I assume privilege-related. I want to save my query after I executed it, but here is the problem...

[image: The blue circle]

Wherever the location, the save button can not be enabled. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the file name in the input box on the top where you have "F:\", append file name there.

For example:

> F:\my_file.sql

Once you type that it will make save button enable.